# OS X Mountain Lion won’t update

Tags: macos, software-update

I am running version `OS X 10.8.2`. In the App Store it shows an update for `OS X 10.8.3`. I tried to update, but it’s showing the following error: `An error occurred while downloading the updates. (102)`.

Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me last night. Close the App Store and Re-Open. Hit Update again next to the 10.8.3 description and it should start up again. This happens when your download connection drops out. The App Store application is actually just a web browsing frame which caches cookies with a delay for queries so it sometimes takes a minute to "refresh" itself to try again.

Comment: yesterday itself i am trying like what you have mentioned... but the same error... even i tried after restarting the machine also the same result...

Comment: try hitting update a few times... I think i pressed it 5-10 times before it fixed itself. You can also try logging out and back in to the app store

Comment: This is not the issue in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can update manually using the [10.8.3 delta update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1641) from Apple.

Comment: If for some reason the delta update fails, try the combo update or post an update to the question with the error message from the installer log.

Comment: Link is dead...