# I can't update my Mac software to the latest version - Error occurred (102)

Tags: software

Every time I click the update button to update my Mac software, a pop up shows up - *An error occurred while loading the update (102)*.

I don't know what to do; I can't update my software.  I hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X Mountain Lion does not updating](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86136/os-x-mountain-lion-does-not-updating)

Answer (score 1):

Launch Terminal and type the following command if
 you are running macOS Sierra:

```
 open `getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR`/com.apple.appstore
```

Move all the files and folders out of com.apple.appstore. Then relaunch Mac App Store.

You can delete all the files and folders later if Mac App Store works well. ​

Comment: In addition to providing a path to resolve this problem, it would be for your answer to include some info as to why your solution will work.  This helps both the OP and others who have the same issue and who are not willing to just run Terminal commands without knowing what it will do.

Comment: The path is dynamic. It's different in everyone's Mac. So I can't give the exact path. It's the quickest way to find the folder with command.

Comment: Sadly this did not work for me. Probably what I get for trying to use a 10 year old Mac.